# sql query inside php login script error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a basic login script for my site and I got stuck. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "*******";
$myDB = "social_bookmarking";

//connection to the database
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$connect = mysqli_connect($myServer,$myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQLServer on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $myDB)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

$email = $_POST['email'];
var_dump($email);
$password = $_POST['passwd'];
var_dump($password);
$query = mysqli_query( $connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
var_dump($query);
if(!$query)
{
    die("Query failed:");
}
else
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM);
    var_dump($row); 
    if($email == $row['email'])
    {
        if($email=='' || $password == '')
        {
            header("Location: index.php?id=Some fields are empty");
        }
        else if ($email==$row['email'] && $password =$row['password']) {
            # code...
            header("Location: main.php?id=$email");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //mysqli_query("alter table users auto_increment = 1");

    }
}   
?>
```

Here is what my code is returning:

```
string 'palade.radupaul@live.com' (length=24)
string '*********' (length=10)
object(mysqli_result)[2]
public 'current_field' => null
public 'field_count' => null
public 'lengths' => null
public 'num_rows' => null
public 'type' => null

array (size=5)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Palade Radu' (length=11)
  2 => string 'pa10der4du' (length=10)
  3 => string 'Radu' (length=4)
  4 => string 'palade.radupaul@live.com' (length=24)
```

This is my table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDaBX.png

I don't know why are all those variables 'null'. Now I get undefined index 'email' under var_dump['row'] . Where am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: Please paste the result in the question, not as an image.

Comment: Do you have a registry with that email ?

Comment: Using `mysqli` without prepared statements opens you up for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: why don't you check both email and password in single query and also use limit 1 in query

Comment: How do I do that, if you don't mind helping me understand?

Comment: Never store plain text passwords! User sha1() function(or another one) to encrypt them.

Comment: I know that the passwords need encryption, but this project is for a class, it doesn't need security, only functionality. Thanks for your concern, I will keep your advice in mind when I will work on a serious project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this modified code

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "*******";
$myDB = "social_bookmarking";

//connection to the database
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$connect = mysqli_connect($myServer,$myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQLServer on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $myDB)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = trim($_POST['passwd']);

if($email=='' || $password == '')
{
    header("Location: index.php?id=Some fields are empty");
    exit;
}
else
{       
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($email));
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($password));

    $query = mysqli_query( $connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1 ");
    if(!$query)
    {
        die("Query failed:");
    }
    else
    {
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            var_dump($row); 
            if($email == $row['user'])
            {
                    # code...
                    header("Location: main.php?id=$email");
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                //mysqli_query("alter table users auto_increment = 1");

            }
        }
        else
        {
           header("Location: index.php?id=Invalid Email ID or Password ");
           exit;
        }       
    }   
}
```

**EDIT-2**

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "*******";
$myDB = "social_bookmarking";

//connection to the database
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$connect = mysqli_connect($myServer,$myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQLServer on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $myDB)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$password = trim($_POST['passwd']);

if($email=='' || $password == '')
{
    header("Location: index.php?id=Some fields are empty");
    exit;
}
else
{       
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($email));
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($password));

    $query = mysqli_query( $connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1 ");
    if(!$query)
    {
        die("Query failed:");
    }
    else
    {
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            # code...
            header("Location: main.php?id=$email");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
           header("Location: index.php?id=Invalid Email ID or Password ");
           exit;
        }       
    }   
}
```

try above code now and see what happened.

Comment: I get undefined index 'email' on this line: if($email == $row['email']) . Do you happen to know what could be the cause for this?

Comment: have you `user` column in your table? and also r u sure that you want to check it with `$email`

Comment: Instead of username, I'm using email for login. I know it's a bit funky, but I'm consistent with it, it shouldn't be a problem. This site will not go online, it is just a project for a class. You can see my table in my post above, I've edited it, look for the image.

Comment: so that means you not column with name 'user' so remove if statement i am posting the edit2 try it.

Comment: @Matt bro its not funky that you are using email instead of username. in most of app we have to use the email address for login, account authentication and it will maintain a unique registration from each email id. it will also used in password recovery etc. so countinue with this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've noticed that if instead of $email I use anything else, it directs me to main.php.